# What is this C# syntax called?

Tags: c#, syntax

In C#, you can do something like this:

```
SomeFunction (() => {
    DoSomething ();
});
```

What is the name of this syntax (the `() => ...`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's a parameterless lambda expression.

Comment: It's a lambda expression even if it's got a statement body. In fact, "anonymous delegate" doesn't exist as standard C# terminology. It would be an anonymous method if it used the "delegate" keyword. Both anonymous methods and lambda expressions are classified as *anonymous functions*.